# Lambda expression for table row & column

Tags: python, matrix, lambda

I am trying to create constraints for my matrix elements, which should validate themselves with lambda functions before simply changing.

This is an example of what I have at the moment (This function should deliver a coordinate [x,y] that is based on another [x,y]:

```
Constraints.append(lambda row,col: [row-1,col+1] )
```

However, executing this results in the following message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Also I tried casting, but then I got the following exception:

```
Constraints.append(lambda row,col: [(int(row)-1),(int(col)+1)] )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite the lambda function so that it accepts arithmetic to produce a new [x,y] coordinate?

Comment: On the face of it, the error message suggests that either `row` or `col` (or both) is a string. This may or may not be what you want. If it is, use `int()` or `float()` to convert them. If not, a more complete example is needed.

Comment: I gave it a try. Added the result to question

Comment: Either `row`  or `col` is a string `'N'`, not an integer. Please show how the complete error traceback and include the relevant code so that we can see how that lambda function is used.

Answer (score -1):

Followed the trace as mkrieger1 suggested. Seemed that the issue was not in the lambda function, but implementing it:

```
File "C:/Users/Algorithm.py", line 78, in CheckConsistency
var = _constraint(int(Assignment[0]),int(Assignment[1]))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'

```
var = _constraint(Assignment[0],Assignment[1])
```

It seems my parameters for Assignment[0] & Assignment[1] were not integers as I expected.